# nginx rewrite rule with query parameter

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

My URL looks like:

```
localhost/video-detail?videoID=T0r-uCXvDzQ
```

I want to serve a page with name:  `T0r-uCXvDzQ.html` (videoID.html) which is present in server's file system.

I am trying to write the rewrite rule as follows:-

```
location / {
      rewrite ^/video-detail?videoID=(.*) /$1.html;
}
```

Also tried:

```
 location / {
   rewrite ^/video-detail?videoID=(.*)  /$arg_videoID.html; 
 }
```

But they are giving 404 error.

How can I use the query parameters in the output rewrite rule.

Comment: Did you enable rewrite_log and see if anything useful was outputted?

Comment: `  rewrite ^/video-detail /$arg_videoID.html; `

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:-

```
if ($args ~* "videoID=(.*)") {
    set $key1 $1;
    rewrite ^(/video-detail)$ /$key1.html;
}
```